# Ensuring your database isn't missing any objects from C#

Tags: c#, database

This is a long shot, but is anyone aware of any libraries that would compare a database schema with [something] (a script, a c# definition, a backup file...anything) and if any fields, tables, relationships are missing, *fix* the database?

The idea being that when a user first starts up a program, it adds all the necessary database objects in, and then if there's a database update any time, it automatically adds that update in, and if the user decides they want to delete a column in the database, it will recreate it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like [ruby on rails migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

There are two libraries I know of that do this - [RikMigrations](http://www.rikware.com/RikMigrations.html) and [MigratorDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) for the .NET platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NHibernate Mappings and schema Export to generate your database and check the schema each time you start you application.